# Python properties and unittest TestCase

Tags: python, unit-testing

Today I wrote test and typoed in one of test methods. My tests failed but I don't understand why. Is it special behaviour of Python properties or something else?

```
from unittest import TestCase


class FailObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FailObject, self).__init__()
        self.__action = None

    @property
    def action(self):
        return self.__action

    @action.setter
    def action(self, value):
        self.__action = value


def do_some_work(fcells, fvalues, action, value):
    currentFailObject = FailObject()
    rects = [currentFailObject]
    return rects


class TestModiAction(TestCase):
    def testSetFailObjectAction(self):
        rect = FailObject  # IMPORTANT PART
        rect.action = "SOME_ACTION" # No fail!
        self.assertEquals("SOME_ACTION", rect.action)

    def testSimple(self):
        fcells = []
        fvalues = []
        rects = do_some_work(fcells, fvalues, 'act', 0.56)

        rect = rects[0]
        self.assertEquals('act', rect.action)
```

When I run this testcase with nose tests:

```
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: testSimple (test.ufsim.office.core.ui.cubeeditor.TestProperty.TestModiAction)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestProperty.py", line 36, in testSimple
    self.assertEquals('act', rect.action)
AssertionError: 'act' != 'SOME_ACTION'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.022s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

If I fix typo with instance creation in **testSetFailObjectAction** all tests are work as expected. But this example turn me back to question: Is it safe to use properties? What if I will typo again some day?

Comment: Are you supposed to be setting `currentFailObject.action = action` in `do_some_work`? Currently nothing should make your (sample) code change `currentFailObject`'s `action` property to `'act'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, that is Python default behaviour. In **testSetFailObjectAction** we add new static class variable that hides our properties. There is no way to protect yourself from mistakes like this.

The only suggestation is to use Traits library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) and [`PropertyMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock)  from [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) to this kind of jobs:

```
@patch(__name__."FailObject.action", new_callable=PropertyMock, return_value="SOME_ACTION")
def testSetFailObjectAction(self, mock_action):
    self.assertEquals("SOME_ACTION", FailObject().action)
    self.assertTrue(mock_action.called)
    #This fail
    self.assertEquals("SOME_ACTION", FailObject.action)
```

By `patch` you replace the property `action` just for the test context and you can also check if the property has been used.